# Multiple input model with PyTorch - input and output features

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor, resnet

Good afternoon!
I’m building a multiple-input model with 2 types of inputs:
Images `(torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224]))` and landmark features `(torch.Size([1, 96]))`.
Here’s the model itself:

```
class MixedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MixedNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        image_modules = list(models.resnet50().children())[:-1]
        self.image_features = nn.Sequential(*image_modules)

        self.landmark_features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=96, out_features=192,bias=False), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(in_features=192,out_features=1000,bias=False), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25))
        
        self.combined_features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1000, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32,1))
        
    def forward(self, image, landmarks):
        a = self.image_features(image)
        print(a.shape)
        b = self.landmark_features(landmarks)
        x = torch.cat((a.view(a.size(0), -1), b.view(b.size(0), -1)), dim=1)
        x = self.combined_features(x)
        x = F.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

I’m getting confused when it comes to defining input-output features for Linear layers and combined layers. The last FC layer of resnet50 Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1000). Does it mean that the last output of self.landmark_features layers also has to be 1000 and the first linear layer of self.combined_features should also be 1000?

Is it correct to assume that if the landmark input size is [1, 96] then the in_features for the first layer of self.landmark_features has to be 96?

With the current dimensions I’m getting the error message:
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x3048 and 1000x512)
(why 3048 and not 2048?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code makes image shape(1, 3, 224, 224) to (1, 2048)

```py
a = self.image_features(image)
a = a.view(a.size(0), -1)
```

And this code makes landmark features shape(1, 96) to (1,1000)

```py
b = self.landmark_features(landmarks)
a = b.view(b.size(0), -1)
```

And torch cat makes concatenate a, b vectors. So, self.combined_features(x) in x's shape is (1, 3048)

So, the code should be changed to the following:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn.functional as F

class MixedNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MixedNetwork, self).__init__()
        
        image_modules = list(models.resnet50().children())[:-1]
        self.image_features = nn.Sequential(*image_modules)

        self.landmark_features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=96, out_features=192,bias=False), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25),
            nn.Linear(in_features=192,out_features=1000,bias=False), 
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            nn.Dropout(p=0.25))
        
        self.combined_features = nn.Sequential(
            # change this input nodes
            nn.Linear(3048, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32,1))
        
    def forward(self, image, landmarks):
        a = self.image_features(image)
        b = self.landmark_features(landmarks)
        x = torch.cat((a.view(a.size(0), -1), b.view(b.size(0), -1)), dim=1)
        x = self.combined_features(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

model = MixedNetwork()
batch_size = 1

# random input
image = torch.randn(batch_size, 3, 224, 224)
land = torch.randn(batch_size, 96)

output = model(image, land)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question - can I concatenate a and b without view?

Comment: No you have to concatenate using the view method. The view method reshapes the matrix. When concatenating matrices, one side of the matrices must be the same length. In this case, the length of the 0th dimension of a and b must be set to 1(batch size) to be concatenated. Do you have any problems using the view method?

Comment: @A_Inb , if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.